# I want to play a sound file at noon daily

Tags: android

I want to play a sound file at 6 am and at noon and at 6 pm daily..
Is it possible..? how can it read the time..?
I think it is like an alram punction..and I want to turn on or off the puntion..
I want your wise answer..

Comment: read this - [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)
this will help you implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager to schedule the event. You can schedule the alarm when ON_BOOT_COMPLETED intent is fired by the OS.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED